# I get undefined while trying to access state from root reducer with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Undefined is returned while trying to access the state.

**Slice:**

```
const initialState = { valid: false };

const validNameSlice = createSlice({
  name: "validName",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    makeNameValid(state) {
      state.valid = true;
    },
    makeNameInvalid(state) {
      state.valid = false;
    }
  }
});

export const {
  makeNameValid,
  makeNameInvalid
} = validNameSlice.actions;
export default validNameSlice.reducer;
```

**Combining the reducers :** (there is actually more than one reducers)

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import validSlice from "./validSlice";

const reducers = {
  validSlice
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
export default rootReducer;
```

**Store:**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducers";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    rootReducer
  }
});

export default store;
```

**Component:**

```
import { makeNameValid, makeNameInvalid } from "./validSlice";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this.props.isValidName);
  };
  handleDispatch = () => {
    this.props.makeNameValid();
  };
  handleDispatchFalse = () => {
    this.props.makeNameInvalid();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>test</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleDispatch()}>Make true</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleDispatchFalse()}>Make false</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isValidName: state.validSlice
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  makeNameValid: () => dispatch(makeNameValid()),
  makeNameInvalid: () => dispatch(makeNameInvalid())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Initially without root reducer it worked, but with root reducer the state in log is returning undefined.

Link to codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-shadow-ii8fs9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You have a tiny error in your configuration - you're wrapping up your rootReducer, but you just need to pass it as the `reducer` parameter:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});
```